# Android BT Scanning (cant be show in TextView)

Tags: android

```
final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver(){
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
         out = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.deviceName);
         out.setText(device.getName());
         btDeviceList.add(device);
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i open the apps and it scan but it does not show anything on my textview.

Comment: @Cindy2011, please edit your original question and include the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the onReceive function is called? Try to print some debug text inside.

If it is called, try to add

```
out = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.deviceName);
out.setText(device.getName());
out.invalidate(); // Add this
```